# splitting and combining categorical data in R

Tags: r

I am new to R so apologies if I am not using correct terminology. I have searched for a solution to following problem but could not find so far.

I have a data frame that has salary data. 
for example,

```
Agency       Position Title   Salary Frequency    Salary  
   abc            BA                Hourly            40
   xyz            QA                Daily             30
   new         Java Developer       Annual          80000
   old         .net Developer       Annual          70000
```

I am trying to normalize the salary column by multiplying hourly rates with 52*40 and daily by 52*5. I have tried if statements and subsetting by salary frequency then using rbind but unfortunately not able to get the results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am not sure if I am able to describe the problem correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
levels(df$Salary.Frequency) <- c(1, 52*5, 52*40)
df$Salary <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Salary.Frequency))*df$Salary
levels(df$Salary.Frequency) <- c("Annual", "Daily", "Hourly")
df
# 1    abc             BA           Hourly  83200
# 2    xyz             QA            Daily   7800
# 3    new Java.Developer           Annual  80000
# 4    old .net.Developer           Annual  70000
```

I used the `levels` function for factors. I could not multiply the Frequency column by the Salary column directly. Because it is of the class `factor`it must be wrapped in the lengthy `as.numeric(as.character(f))` or the even more archaic `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` first before arithmetic operations. Side note: You're multiplying by 52; those hourly and daily workers don't get any vacation? : )

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="Agency       Position.Title   Salary.Frequency    Salary  
   abc            BA                Hourly            40
   xyz            QA                Daily             30
   new         Java.Developer       Annual          80000
   old         .net.Developer       Annual          70000", header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was a creative answer. Answer to the side note: Maybe in this case they don't :)

Answer (score 2):

I work most comfortably in [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started); here's how I would do it:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,Salary:=Salary*(52^(Salary.Frequency!="Annual"))*
     (5^(Salary.Frequency=="Daily"))*
     (40^(Salary.Frequency=="Hourly"))]
> df
   Agency Position.Title Salary.Frequency Salary
1:    abc             BA           Hourly  83200
2:    xyz             QA            Daily   7800
3:    new Java.Developer           Annual  80000
4:    old .net.Developer           Annual  70000
```

---

an alternative which may be easier to digest would be:

```
df[Salary.Frequency=="Daily",Salary:=200*Salary]
df[Salary.Frequency=="Hourly",Salary:=40*52*Salary]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution with two nested `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Salary = ifelse( Salary.Frequency == "Hourly",
                                         (Salary * 52 * 40),
                                ifelse( Salary.Frequency == "Annual",
                                        Salary, (Salary * 52 * 5)
                                       )))

 Agency Position.Title Salary.Frequency Salary
1    abc             BA           Hourly  83200
2    xyz             QA            Daily   7800
3    new Java.Developer           Annual  80000
4    old .net.Developer           Annual  70000
```